# OnItemSelected not being called

Tags: android

This should be simple but I'm having a lot of trouble with an AutoCompleteTextView having it's OnItemSelected method being called.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    private List<Contact> contactsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> forAutoComplete = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Contact> selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    AutoCompleteTextView textView;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, forAutoComplete);
    textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
            "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    textView.setText("");
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    Toast.makeText( this,
            "Nothing selected",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    textView.setText("");
}
```

None of my toasts are being called.

Thanks.

Comment: TextViews should utilize OnClickListeners. OnItemSelectedListeners are for ListViews.

Comment: Yep, thought it wasn't working before when I tried implementing that but I now realize a mistake I had made with my attempt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Althought in docs I noticed that it is valid to use `onItemSelectedListener`.

For AutoComplete TextView, you should use `onItemClickListener`, since it's more correct than other, as the ItemSelect is more specified for `ListViews`.

Check [this tutorial](https://androiddesk.wordpress.com/tag/autocompletetextview-in-android-with-example/) on how to use it. Dont forget to initialize your Listener!

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten to do that.

Comment: No problem :) I think even your onItemSelectedListener could work if you initialize it corret (new onItem..).  Good luck! :)

Comment: It didn't, I had it initialized but removed it while I was in the "trying anything to make it work" phase.